# How to declare delegate on non-ARC

Tags: objective-c, properties, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I'm a newbie in Objective-C and would like to know in depth regarding non-ARC. Could someone tell me how to declare a delegate property in non-ARC. I know that in ARC it is declared to be weak. i.e.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyOwnDelegate> delegate;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should think ARC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare it with `assign`, meaning it is not retained, when you set the delegate property, but simply assigned.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyOwnDelegate> delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the framework classes, such as UITableView:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate
```

i.e. use 'assign' to indicate that it is not retained.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code in my project.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <myOwnDelegate> delegate;
```